# How to have the multiple radio button stay checked on the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my code below.

```
<div class="filter_client_search_container">
<div class="filter_search_box" style="margin-top:15px;float:left;margin-right:5px;width:349px;">
    <div class="filter_field">  
        <input type="radio" id="allindividuals" name="clienttype">
        <label for="allindividuals" style="width:260px">All Individuals</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_field">
        <input type="radio" id="byindividual" name="clienttype">
        <label for="byindividual" style="width:146px;">By Individual Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="clientcriteria">
    </div>
    <div class="filter_search_criteria" style="left:186px;">
        <input type="button" name="APPLY" value="Apply">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="filter_search_box" style="margin-top:15px;float:left;width:352px;margin-right:5px;">
    <div class="filter_field">  
        <input type="radio" id="allcompanies" name="clienttype" value="allclients" checked>
        <label for="allcompanies" style="width:260px;">All Companies</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_field">
        <input type="radio" id="bycompany" name="clienttype" value="byclient">
        <label for="bycompany" style="width:149px;">By Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="byclientcriteria">
    </div>
    <div class="filter_search_criteria" style="left:189px;">
        <input type="button" name="APPLY" value="Apply">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I got here is that I have the "filter_client_search_container" div which contains two filter search boxes div.  Each filter search box has a couple of radio buttons of their own and what I want is that I should have the ability to check one radio button in the first filter search box, and then check the other one in the second filter search box.  But i'm only allowed to have only one radio button to check in one single page, thus I couldn't have multiple radio buttons checked??

But why couldn't I acccomplish this using this approach... I would have thought the two filter search boxes would make the radio buttons independent of each other...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons are to choose only one value and as Dryden said, the radio buttons that share name="clienttype" will share the selection, and only one can be active, so change the name attribute or if you want multiple choices better use checkbox.

Comment: Thanks Coronellx.  Great tip here!

Answer (score 4):

Radio buttons are linked by the `name` attribute. Of all the `name="clienttype"` radio buttons, you can only choose 1. If you want to choose multiple, change them to check boxes, or change the name value.

After re-reading your post, it looks like what you need to do is give the same name to the radio buttons in one div, and then give a different name to the radio buttons in the other div. For example, something like this:

```
<div class="filter_client_search_container">
<div class="filter_search_box" style="margin-top:15px;float:left;margin-right:5px;width:349px;">
    <div class="filter_field">  
        <input type="radio" id="allindividuals" name="clienttype1">
        <label for="allindividuals" style="width:260px">All Individuals</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_field">
        <input type="radio" id="byindividual" name="clienttype1">
        <label for="byindividual" style="width:146px;">By Individual Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="clientcriteria">
    </div>
    <div class="filter_search_criteria" style="left:186px;">
        <input type="button" name="APPLY" value="Apply">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="filter_search_box" style="margin-top:15px;float:left;width:352px;margin-right:5px;">
    <div class="filter_field">  
        <input type="radio" id="allcompanies" name="clienttype2" value="allclients" checked>
        <label for="allcompanies" style="width:260px;">All Companies</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_field">
        <input type="radio" id="bycompany" name="clienttype2" value="byclient">
        <label for="bycompany" style="width:149px;">By Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="byclientcriteria">
    </div>
    <div class="filter_search_criteria" style="left:189px;">
        <input type="button" name="APPLY" value="Apply">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Notice the difference in the `name` attributes.

Comment: Thanks Dryden!  This is precisely the desire behaviour of radio buttons I need to get them to work on my project.  Thanks a lot!!